# Not able to Subtract 1 day from New Year date using java(1-1-2100)

Tags: java

I just want to subtract 1 day from *New year* date in my current scenario.
    But while I subtract I get date: `31-0-2100`.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2100, 1, 1);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
String dateStr = ""+cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+
    "-"+cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println(dateStr);
```

The actual date should be: `31-12-2099`

Comment: What date do you think `31-0-2100` is? What could it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're doing `cal.set(2100, 1, 1);`, the date you set is actually the first day of February and not January since months are 0 base indexed (`0 -> January, ..., 11 -> December`).

I would recommend you to use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which is a far better library to deal with dates and time.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2100, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
date = date.minusDays(1);
System.out.println(date.toString("dd-MM-yyyy")); //31-12-2099
```

Or if you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), they introduced a [brand-new date and time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2100, Month.JANUARY, 1);
date = date.minusDays(1);
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))); //31-12-2099
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but would be better if you specified a time zone object ([DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html)) as a last argument on the DateTime constructor. If omitted, the JVM's default time zone will be applied to that new DateTime value.

Comment: Also, generally best to call the [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) method on DateTime rather than assuming `00:00:00` is the first moment of the day. Because of Daylight Saving Time or other anomalies, the day may start at a later time of day.

Answer (score 1):

In java the month 0 is January.

So what you got is correct since you're substracting 1 day from February 1st 2100

Comment: So what should i do i this case? Any suggestion

Comment: Replace the following in your code:
cal.set(2100, 0, 1);
It's the new year's day

Comment: Use the month constants defined in the Calendar class. Or even better: use the new Date and Time API if you can use Java SE 8.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the field MONTH is 0-indexed, so the month '1' is actually February and what you are getting: '31-0'2100' is the last day of January.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented using Calendar functionality.

Tested and Executed

```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   cal.set(2099, 00, 01);
   cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
   System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Another solution Formulate the DateTime using the below methods

```
date.getYear();
date.getDay();
date.getMonth();
```

Try to pass those arguments into the DateTime.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2100, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
date = date.minusDays(1);
System.out.println(date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: DateTime is not a JDK class. I guess you mean the class from JodaTime, but this should be mentioned.

Comment: @Puce  - Added one more solution to implement this using calendar.

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead:

```
call.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1)
```

Comment: Same result is getting displayed. I have also used (Calender.Hour, -24)